# How to detect if another component is present in the document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reach-router, react-static

I have a site built with [React Static](https://github.com/react-static/react-static) that has a Header component that is always present. Depending on if the current page has a hero component or not, the Header should be either light or dark.

The Header is rendered outside of the routes and the `useEffect` is triggered before the children is rendered. This is *probably* because of the routing.

This is the current code:

```
// App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Root, Routes } from 'react-static'

export default () => {

    const [useDarkTheme, setUseDarkTheme] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
            const heroPresent = document.querySelectorAll(".o-hero").length > 0;
            console.log("The hero is present: " + heroPresent);
            setUseDarkTheme(!heroPresent);
        }
    })

    return (
        <Root>
            <React.Suspense fallback={ <em>Loading...</em> }>
                <Header useDarkTheme={ useDarkTheme } />
                <Routes default />
            </React.Suspense>
        </Root>
    );
}
```

What will be rendered at `<Routes default />` is the static pages configured in React Static's `static.config.js`.

Below is an example of the Hero component:

```
// Hero.js
import React from "react";

export default () => {
    console.log("This is the Hero rendering. If this exist, the Header should be dark.");

    return (
        <div className="o-hero">
            <p>Hero!</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I run the application and look at the logs this is what I get:

```
The hero is present: false
This is the Hero rendering. If this exist, the Header should be dark.
```

How could I somehow detect the presence of the Hero from the Header although the Hero is in a router and the Header is not? This feels like quite a common use case, but I could not find any info on the interwebs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try with timeouts ... but in fact it's crying for `useContext` - it's not about detecting but about communication

Comment: @xadm yes, timeouts work indeed but is not the best solution IMHO. I have never heard of useContext, I will look it up! Thanks

Comment: @xadm I ended up using the `useContext` way by using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component and it worked great. If you want, you could write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: you can answer your own question, we can comment if it can be improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using `useContext` to provide all children with a getter and a setter for the Header's theme (dark or light). The solution is very much inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component).  The solution looks like this:

```
// App.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Root, Routes } from 'react-static'
import { HeaderThemeContext } from "./context";

export default () => {

    const { theme } = useContext(HeaderThemeContext);
    const [headerTheme, setHeaderTheme] = useState(theme);

    return (
        <Root>
            <React.Suspense fallback={ <em>Loading...</em> }>
                <HeaderThemeContext.Provider value={ { theme: headerTheme, setTheme: setHeaderTheme } }>
                    <Header theme={ headerTheme } />
                    <Routes default />
                </HeaderThemeContext.Provider>
            </React.Suspense>
        </Root>
    );
}
```

```
// Hero.js
import React from "react";
import { headerThemes, setHeaderTheme } from "./context";

export default () => {
    setHeaderTheme(headerThemes.DARK); 

    console.log("This is the Hero rendering. If this exist, the Header should be dark.");

    return (
        <div className="o-hero">
            <p>Hero!</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
// context.js
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const headerThemes = {
    LIGHT: "light",
    DARK: "dark",
};

export const HeaderThemeContext = createContext({
    theme: headerThemes.LIGHT,
    setTheme: () => {}
});

// This is a hook and can only be used in a functional component with access to the HeaderThemeContext.
export const setHeaderTheme = theme => useContext(HeaderThemeContext).setTheme(theme);
```

This gives global access to set and get the header theme, which might not be optional, but it works for now and I think it's fine. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.