# Typescript error - Unable to find react context in wrapped child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I'm trying to dynamically set context in a parent component from a child component using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component) as a guide

Here's my App.tsx:

```
export interface User {
  username: string;
}

export interface iUserContext {
  users: User[];
  setUsers: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User[]>>;
}

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const value = { users, setUsers };

  // set defaults
  const UsersContext = createContext<iUserContext>({
    users: [],
    setUsers: () => {},
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <UsersContext.Provider value={value}>
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/generated-links">
                <GeneratedLinks />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <GenerateLinks />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </UsersContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, in GenerateLinks.tsx:

```
const GenerateLinks = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { users, setUsers } = useContext<iUserContext>(UsersContext);
```

The error I'm getting is for the UsersContext argument, just here ^:

```
Cannot find name 'UsersContext'. Did you mean 'useContext'?
```

I haven't used useContext and TS together before, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it seems like TS isn't detecting that I'm wrapping this component with the users context provider and passing in. Any ideas?

Comment: you should create context outside of your component and export its instance to children as useContext arguments

Comment: move the context creation out of the component, React is thinking that you are using a hook and is suggesting this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UsersContext` should be outside the `App` component and marked for export.

```
export interface iUserContext {
  users: User[];
  setUsers: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User[]>>;
}

export const UsersContext = createContext<iUserContext>({
  users: [],
  setUsers: () => {},
});

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const value = { users, setUsers };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <UsersContext.Provider value={value}>
```

Then, you can import it in `GenerateLinks`:

```
import { UsersContext, iUserContext } from './App'
```

Comment: why? this is bypassing react

Comment: @johnk React's [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext#createcontext) state: "`createContext` returns a context object. **The context object itself does not hold any information.** It represents *which* context other components read or provide. Typically, you will use `SomeContext.Provider` in components above to specify the context value, and call `useContext(SomeContext)` in components below to read it.". - So the context object should be created at the module level, or otherwise it will be a *different* context object each time.

Comment: You said "the context object itself does not hold any information".  So It's a pointer. 
 What is the significance of it being a 'different' pointer, as long as it points to the same information?