# Having trouble with UseContext with ReactJs, I need to change the state variable in one component and want that updated state in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

This is my App.js

```
function App() {
   const [patient, setPatient] = useState("1")

  return (
      <div className="App" >

        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <DepNamesContext.Provider value={{patient, setPatient}}  > 
            <Route exact path="/" >
              <HomePage   />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/EmployeeSurvey/:email/:firstName/:lastName/:code">
              <NormalSurvey />
            </Route>
            <Route  path="/VisitorSurvey/:email/:firstName/:lastName/:code" >
              <VisitorSurvey />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/NewVisitorSurvey/:email/:firstName/:lastName/:code">
              <NewVisitorSurvey />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/ConsentPage/:email/:firstName/:lastName/:code/:companyName">
              <Consent />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Pass/:code/:name/:email">
              <Pass />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Fail/:code">
              <Fail />
            </Route>
          
          </DepNamesContext.Provider> 

          </Switch>
        </Router>
       
      </div>
    );
  } 
export default App;
```

This is a portion from Homepage.js

```
import { DepNamesContext } from "./DepNamesContext"
   const {setPatient,patient} = useContext(DepNamesContext);
```

I'd use setPatientMinor("3") and it will get updated in the homepage.js component but when I try and access patient state in VisitorSurvey.js Component, it's still the initial value of "1"

Comment: Suggestion: See if you can reduce the size of the example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's not how Context works afaik: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext A context's value is changed by changing what you pass as `value` into the provider.

Comment: Is there a reason why you put Provider inside Switch? *when I try and access patient state in VisitorSurvey.js Component, it's still the initial value of "1"* - what are both comps?

Comment: @ChrisG That makes sense, i'm quite new to ReactJs, thank you. do you have any suggestions to how I could solve the issue. I tried using Mobx and pullstate but it didn't work.

Comment: @EstusFlask No reason, I could put it outside but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Duplicate: [How to update React Context from inside a child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component)