# useContext is returning returning the initial value and not the assigned value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

This is my first time using usecontext,and i got stuck with this problem,where the usecontext returns the initial value and not the passed value.

This is my App.js

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import {userprop} from './Context'

function App() {

  const value = useContext(userprop)
  console.log(value)
  return (
    <div >
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Context.js

```
import React, { useState ,createContext} from 'react'
import App from './App'

export const userprop  =createContext(0)

function Context(){
    const [a,seta] = useState(2)
    return(
        <userprop.Provider value={3}>
            <App/>
        </userprop.Provider>
    )
}
export default Context;
```

Iam getting the output as 0 and not 2 !!
How can i solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update React Context from inside a child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component)

Comment: are  you rendering `App` as root component?

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching it the wrong way. The Context **Provider** should wrap everything that wants to **consume** the context.

Making minimal changes to your code :

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { userprop } from "./Context";

function App() {
  const value = useContext(userprop);
  console.log(value);
  return <div></div>;
}

export default App;
```

Also, you are not passing the state value into the context, but instead a hard coded number 3. So that needs change too:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import App from "./App";

export const userprop = createContext(0);

function Context() {
  const [a, seta] = useState(2);
  return (
    <userprop.Provider value={a}>
      <App />
    </userprop.Provider>
  );
}
export default Context;
```

Now, you have to mount `Context` as your main component into the `div` instead of `App` though.

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-haze-2lndr5?file=/src/Context.js:0-387)