# React TypeScript: Making result of an API call available elsewhere

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React/TypeScript application that makes requests of a REST API.

One of the components in my app requests information that I would like to be able to use elsewhere, in other components.

Is it possible to make this API call in some other folder, and then import the result into my components where needed?

Or is it necessary to request this information each time it is needed?

I am quite new to React, so not sure what the intended way of doing this is

Comment: You need a global store. Or you need to structure your app in a manner that the information reaches the closest common ancestor. 
Sometimes you can put questions like these on GPT

Answer (score -1):

Starting from what others said, the basic knowledge you need is about [React context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

This makes so that a parent component (called the `Context provider`) passes some data to all its children, which can be accessed by a `useContext` hook. A powerful behavior is that children can modify too the context value, by using a setter function available from the context itself. I suggest you to check [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component) and its accepted answer.