# How to send data from a child component to its sibling?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, preact, freshjs

I want create an app with two forms, each form in its own component. Users type in form 1, then the data will be passed to component 2. In there it will join the data of what they type in form 2. How can I do this in Fresh (Preact)?

Here is my attempt when following the first answer in [How to update React Context from inside a child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41030361/3416774):

##### `index.jsx`

```js
import { createContext } from "preact";
import { Form1Context } from "../islands/Context.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <Form1Context.Provider value="dark">
      <Form1 />
      <Form2 />
    </Form1Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

##### `Context.js`

```js
import { createContext } from 'preact'

export const Form1Context = createContext({
    form1Data: 'Form 1 placeholder',
    setInput: () => {} 
}) 

export function Form1Provider({ children }) {
    const [form1Data, setInput] = useState('Form 1 placeholder');

    return (
        <Form1Context.Provider value = {form1Data} >
            {children} 
        </Form1Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

##### `Form1.jsx`

```js
import { useContext, useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Form1(props) {
  const {form1Data, setForm1Data } = useContext(Form1Provider)
    
  return (
    <textarea 
    value = {form1Data} 
    onInput={(event) => setForm1Data(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

##### `Form2.jsx`

```js
import { useContext, useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Form2(props) {
  const {form1Data, setForm1Data } = useContext(Form1Provider)
  const {form2Data, setForm2Data } = useState('Form 2 placeholder')
    
  return (
    <>
        <textarea 
            value = {form2Data} 
            onInput={(event) => setForm2Data(event.target.value)}
        />
        <p>The value is {form1Data} + {form2Data}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

The app compiles fine, but the actual result is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the provider wrapper you created (with the form1 state in it):

**index.jsx**

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Form1Provider>
      <Form1 />
      <Form2 />
    </Form1Provider>
  );
}
```

The context is declared in a strange way, I suggest:

**Context.jsx**

```js
export const Form1Context = createContext(null);

export function Form1Provider({ children }) {
  const form1State = useState('Form 1 placeholder');
  return (
    <Form1Context.Provider value={form1State}>{children}</Form1Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

When calling `useContext` you need to use the context, not the provider. Use square brackets in this case since we return the result of `useState`.

**Form1.jsx**

```
export default function Form1(props) {
  const [form1Data, setForm1Data] = useContext(Form1Context);

  return (
    <textarea
      value={form1Data}
      onInput={(event) => setForm1Data(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

You're also misusing `useState` - you need to destructure with square brackets since it returns an array:

**Form2.jsx**

```
export default function Form2(props) {
  const [form1Data] = useContext(Form1Context);
  const [form2Data, setForm2Data] = useState('Form 2 placeholder');

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        value={form2Data}
        onInput={(event) => setForm2Data(event.target.value)}
      />
      <p>
        The value is {form1Data} + {form2Data}
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz demo with react: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yyjto3?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Stackbliz requires me to re-fresh the result when opening it for the first time in order to see it. Since I'm working on Fresh/React, I guess I don't need to create an empty html and can directly write the `App.tsx` content in `index.tsx` (as I notice you already does that in your answer). However it still doesn't work on my machine. On `Form1` in line `[form1Data, setForm1Data]` and on `Form2` in `[form1Data]` I get `Type 'null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` I notice the `useContext(Form1Context)` lines in both forms are not consistent. Why is that?

Comment: When you say "I get <error>", do you mean you get an error at runtime, or your IDE is complaining? My guess is you didn't provide the value via `Form1Provider` so you got the default `null` value. Either that or you're using some kind of type linter like Typescript in your IDE that infers the type of the context to be `null`.

Comment: you are right. I was copying your code and you specified the `null` value in there. I wonder why you did that? I put something in there and it doesn't seem to do anything. Also, in the Preact documentation of [`useContext()`](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#usecontext), the result of it is not an array but directly the string. Why is that? I try following it and the default value of the context becomes `Form 1 placeholder,function(a2){var f=t.__N?t.__N[0]:t.__[0],s=t.t(f,a2);f!==s&&(t.__N=[s,t.__[1]],t.__c.setState({}))}`

Comment: I put null as the default value in order to purposely throw an error if you forget to provide an actual value, that's just my preference. The result of `useContext` is whatever value you happen to return via the `value` property of the provider. If you are using typescript you need to specify the return value with `createContext<MyReturnType>(null as any)`. You also forgot to answer my question.

Comment: I see. The error is the IDE complaining

Comment: That means your IDE is using some type of linter like eslint or a typescript language server. Since all your files were labelled as 'jsx' instead of 'tsx' I assumed this was not the case. Can you please provide the full message including what program is throwing the error. Generally there will be a prefix like `eslint:` or `tsc`.

Comment: well, I use tsx, but write the question in jsx to not get distracted by the type errors. It's all clear to me now. Is your preference of purposely use null for educational purpose or a good habit when programing? Because if you don't need to teach others then why don't you just fill the value in there?

Comment: I recommend using null as the default value so that you immediately know if you forgot to provide an actual value, otherwise you'll just silently get some empty values. It'll also save a bunch of time and dead code for larger, more complex contexts. Why provide a default value if you never plan on using it? But that's just my opinion. As a side note, if you are working in Typescript, it's best to make that clear and tag the question as such so you can get a complete answer. Cheers.

Comment: If possible, can you make your answer working with Typescript? For example, in your link, why does it say `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.(2339)`?

Comment: @Ooker, updated. Seems to be an issue with the type definitions, they should be able to infer that `event.target` is an `HTMLTextAreaElement` but I had to cast it explicitly.