React - multiple form fields dependent button enabling
My React web app has the below layout in a page:
a. Common “Info” section (form) at the upper half.
b. Say 4 different “Details” tabs in the lower half. (Also forms)
Now I have a button in a. that needs to be enabled/disabled based on form field values filled across b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 forms.
How can I best solve this? I tried the below..

With Formik and Yup validations - I gather that all related fields must be wrapped in the same form component, so that’s out.

We could try getting data from API on mount, for all 4 tab forms (b1-b4), do a validation on the fly and set flag for disable/enable button in a. (Phew! That sounds like a lot of over head!)

Any other approaches?



https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030361/how-to-update-react-context-from-inside-a-child-component  I think context will work for you.
